# Checking if a list exists in a list of lists before adding the list. The method Contains is not working to my expectation

Tags: c#

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I have looked over some of them, but I'm still quite confused.

So, I'm trying to find unique lists of two integers that when divided together, would result in a positive non-decimal value, and both numbers cannot be the same.

I have done pretty everything to my knowledge, and this is the best version I have:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> divSet = new List<int>();
        List<List<int>> uniqueDivSets = new List<List<int>>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        void findEasyDivisons(int beginning, int end)
        {
            int x = rand.Next(beginning, end);
            int y = rand.Next(beginning, end);

            // I only want 3 sets
            if (uniqueDivSets.Count >= 3)
            {
                return;
            }
            // checks if the resultant divison is positive and non-decimal and that the two numbers aren't the same
            else if (x % y == 0 && x != y)
            {
                divSet = new List<int> { x, y };

                // checks if such a list already exists in uniqueDivSets or not
                if (!uniqueDivSets.Contains(divSet))
                {
                    uniqueDivSets.Add(divSet);
                }
            }

            findEasyDivisons(beginning, end);
            return;
        }

        findEasyDivisons(2, 8);
        

        // just for checking the numbers in the console
        Console.WriteLine(uniqueDivSets[0][0].ToString() + " " + uniqueDivSets[0][1].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(uniqueDivSets[1][0].ToString() + " " + uniqueDivSets[1][1].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(uniqueDivSets[2][0].ToString() + " " + uniqueDivSets[2][1].ToString());
    }
}
```

However, this results in 3 lists that are rarely unique from each other. Is using the method `Contains` the way I used it completely wrong? Or perhaps this has something to do with memory and referencing that I don't quite understand yet?

I have no clue what I'm missing honestly and this is my last attempt at finding a solution before saying "screw it, will just keep it as random as it was.".

While this is very fast in execution, I wouldn't mind a performance tweak if you know of one. My solution just looks very crude.

And for context, this is just a snippet in a separate file of an assignment for college. We need to make a "MathQuiz" WinForms project that takes into account the level of difficulty, the hypothetical audience being children, and optionally rounds in each difficulty.

Comment: You need to know if you want to check to see if a List is contained or its content, ie you need to understand reference variables. You may need to write a compare/equals function. `Contains`  will not test the content but only the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have a wrong data structures for a task - since you care only about pairs - just use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple), value tuples to be precise (which already has equality methods generated for you). Next recommendation would be to place values always in the same order, this will make comparisons easier, and lastly - use [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) which should handle duplicates for you (with O(1) complexity at least in amortized scenario, though since you need only 3 pairs it does not matter that much, actually it could be worse in terms of performance).

- `var uniqueDivSets = new List<List<int>>();` -> `var uniqueDivSets = new HashSet<(int, int)>()`
- `divSet = new List<int> { x, y }` -> `var divSet = (Math.Min(x, y), Math.Max(x, y))`; (and remove outer scope declaration)
- and the following:

  ```cs
  if (!uniqueDivSets.Contains(divSet))
  {
       uniqueDivSets.Add(divSet);
  }
  ```

  change just to `uniqueDivSets.Add(divSet);`

If you want to stick to original code with lists - then you need to provide custom `IEqualityComparer`. I still would recommend to put items in the list sorted, but in general case it could like the following (if you do not want to "presort"):

```cs
class PairListEqComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public static PairListEqComparer Instance { get; } = new PairListEqComparer();

    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.Count != 2 || y.Count != 2) return false; // or throw

        return x.Max() == y.Max() && x.Min() == y.Min();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj) => HashCode.Combine(obj.Max(), obj.Min(), obj.Count);
}
```

And usage:

```
if (!uniqueDivSets.Contains(divSet, PairListEqComparer.Instance))
{
    uniqueDivSets.Add(divSet);
}
```